# Using GitPython module to get remote HEAD branch

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I'm trying to use GitPython to write some Python scripts which I can use it to simplify my daily tasks as I manage many branches.

I'm also quite new for Python when it comes to writing complicated scripts.

This is the API I used: [GitPython API doc](http://packages.python.org/GitPython/0.3.2/index.html)

I want to write it in GitPython that simply does the following and parse out the part which shows me the HEAD remote branch is pointing. In another word, I want to basically get the `remotes/origin/HEAD`

```
$ git branch -a
  master
* branch_to_remove
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/testing
```

I browse the API doc many times, at first I'm having trouble to understand the Python format of these API docs, and I couldn't find anything useful to use to do for this other than `remote_head` in `class git.refs.reference.Reference(repo, path, check_path=True)`

But I don't even know how to call/initialize it.

Here is what I had so far, and you can tell what I'm trying to do, to simply reset to 'no branch' state and remove the current branch I'm on:

```
import git
from git import *
repo = git.Repo("/some/path/testing")
repo.git.branch()
[some code to get the remotes/origin/HEAD, set it to remoteHeadBranch ]
repo.git.checkout(remoteHeadBranch)  # this should reset the Git back to 'no branch' state
repo.git.checkout(D="branch_to_remove")
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I just saw your question I was wondering about this gitPython, looks like  really nice tool, and I was looking for this specific question in the GitPython documentation with no lucky but if you search on github you will see a lot of tests there and there's a test for that.

You will see something like this when you search for "remove new branch":

```
# remove new branch
Head.delete(new_remote_branch.repo, new_remote_branch)
```

[GitPython Reference](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/master/git/test/test_remote.py)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I will try this out!

Can someone please help me a bit when reading these Python API docs? I meant the doc is very different and hard for me to read for a Java guy like me :-(

Thanks!

Comment: This will *NOT* work because you cannot delete the branch you are currently on, so the first step is always return back to the 'no branch' state which what I'm trying to do.

`Error on switching to 'no' branch state.
'git branch -d newMaster' returned exit status 1: error: Cannot delete the branch 'newMaster' which you are currently on.`

Answer (score 3):

To print the current branch:

```
print(repo.head.ref)
```

To list branches

```
print [str(b) for b in repo.heads]
```

To checkout a branch

```
repo.heads[branch].checkout()
```

or `repo.git.checkout(branch)`

If you're trying to delete a branch, You need to be in a different LOCAL branch, which you can do in several ways

```
repo.heads['master'].checkout()
```

or `repo.git.checkout('master')`
or `repo.git.checkout('remotes/origin/master')`

Hope this helps

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with the question. The asker is specifically asking about the HEAD of a remote.

Answer (score 1):

`next(ref for ref in repo.remotes.origin.refs if ref.name == "origin/HEAD").ref.name`

`repo.remotes.origin.refs` will give you a list of the remote branches. Filter on the one that is the *HEAD* and check towards what it points(ref<.name>).

You are now left with something like `"origin/master"` or `"origin/main"`.

Comment: For me `[ref for ref in repo.remotes.origin.refs if ref.name == "origin/HEAD"]` gives an empty list. I use `git version 2.36.2`.